# Get authorization rules from web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

In web config I have several location-based authorization rules like:

```
<location path="error.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

How can I get all these rules in code (ASP.NET)?

Comment: What are you trying to do?Just asking.

Comment: I'm trying to apply custom authorization for anonymou-allowed pages

Comment: Just a quick thought, have you looked into WIF ClaimsAuthN/ ClaimsAuthZ managers to do encapsulate your authorization logic?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out:

```
var config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
var section = config.GetSection("system.web/authorization") as AuthorizationSection;

foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in section.Rules)
{
    if (rule.Action.ToString().ToLower() == "allow")
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Dig deep into AuthorizationRule class properties.

You can read more here: http://lajak.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/read-authorization-section-from-web-config/